Vanilla JS WebSocket object can properly set protocol value but "ws" package required by node cannot set protocol?
I'm currently trying to create a WebSocket object using node (version 18.17.0) but every time I try to set the protocol using the "ws" library it never sets it and it always ends up as an empty string.
Interestingly, the Vanilla JS WebSocket object can easily connect with a specified protocol (used jsfiddle.net). Wanted to know if it's something to do with me trying to create the WebSocket object server-side compared to the browser version of JS?
I'm only using the "ws" package because node won't let me just use the Vanilla JS WebSocket and forces me to import the library with a ReferenceError.
Any tips are appreciated!
const ws = new WebSocket("url", ["graphql-ws"]);

const ws = new WebSocket("url", "graphql-ws");

const ws = new WebSocket("url", {protocol: "graphql-ws"});

These are the three different variations I've tried to create for the object and for some reason the protocol never gets set (url is fine).
I also tried sleeping the function and letting it set but sleeping just makes the connection immediately error out. A while loop waiting for the readyState of the WebSocket just stays in the loop forever as well.
Expecting it to be like the browser Vanilla JS environment I used where it can pretty easily connect.
Followup: on Vanilla JS I can just do
const ws = new WebSocket("url", ["graphql-ws"]);

and it works perfectly.

Feel super dumb right now but it's because (in my case) all the clients on the browser had a user agent but I neglected to put on in the options for my server-side WebSocket.
